# In Protocol-Buffers, why does adding a new optional field with a nested type breaks the Forward compatibility?

Tags: protocol-buffers, aws-glue

I have the current message:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my.package;
    
message MySchemaTest {
  int32 foo = 1;
  string provider_hotel_id = 2;
}
```

I want to upgrade it to something like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my.package;
    
message MySchemaTest {
  int32 foo = 1;
  string provider_hotel_id = 2;
  optional Coordinate location = 3;

  message Coordinate {
    double longitude = 10;
    double latitude = 11;
 }
}
```

It also fails with:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package my.package;

message Coordinate {
  optional double longitude = 10;
  optional double latitude = 11;
}
    
message MySchemaTest {
  int32 foo = 1;
  string provider_hotel_id = 2;
  optional Coordinate location = 3;
}
```

It fails trying to register the new schema in AWS Glue Schema. Apparently for compatibility reasons.  If I change from forward to backwards it seems to allow it.

[image]

Questions:

- Is there any workaround to add the new type with compatibility for the current consumers?
- Is this limitation specific to AWS Glue or part protocol-buffers design for evolution?

More info:

Cloud trail event is not very helpful:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "eventTime": "2023-07-05T08:46:40Z",
    "eventSource": "glue.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "RegisterSchemaVersion",
    "requestParameters": {
        "schemaId": {
            "schemaName": "bar",
            "registryName": "foo"
        },
        "schemaDefinition": "syntax = \"proto3\";\n\npackage my.package;\n\nmessage Coordinate {\n  optional double longitude = 10;\n  optional double latitude = 11;\n}\n    \nmessage MySchemaTest {\n  int32 foo = 1;\n  string provider_hotel_id = 2;\n  optional Coordinate location = 3;\n}"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "schemaVersionId": "c04790c7-8153-4f34-a9a2-5c6da813617a",
        "versionNumber": 2,
        "status": "FAILURE"
    },
    "requestID": "ecad15ca-3717-4913-96db-25a737b6db70",
    "eventID": "6f2807c2-e9c7-4583-a5ed-b318b8db3470",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "230241594797",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "tlsDetails": {
        "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.3",
        "cipherSuite": "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "clientProvidedHostHeader": "glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
}
```

Comment: *Apparently for compatibility reasons.* Please show the exact error raised by AWS Glue.

Comment: @273K That is a good point. Amazon doesn't show any error.  We have checked CloudWatch and CloudTrail but we have found no error message

Comment: What changes if you move `message Coordinate` out of `message MySchemaTest`, to the top of the .proto file?

Comment: @273K Unfortunately it also fails

Comment: *It also fails with:* Of course it fails, because `Coordinate` in `MySchemaTest` is not defined. Swap them, as I said it: `message Coordinate` ... to the top of the .proto file.

Comment: @273K Tested again with it at the top and updated message. But made no difference

Comment: In my personal account I have been able to add a cloud trail event...  but not very helpful anyway. Just a failure without message